# Gradle (ProGuard) Exception while processing task java.io (Duplicate zip entry)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play, proguard, play-billing-library

When I build a release version I get the following gradle warning:

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: 
Can't write [C:\Users\MyName\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\free\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar]
(Can't read [C:\Users\MyName\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\classes\free\release(;;;;;;**.class)]
(Can't read [com] (Can't read [android] (Can't read [vending] (Can't read [billing]
(Can't read [IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]
(Duplicate zip entry [com/android/a/a/a$a$a.class == com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class])))))))
```

and error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForFreeRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

Probably some sort of ProGuard issue.  It's since I've been trying to implement the new [Play Billing Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library.html).  I've tried to clean and rebuild the project (several times), and invalidate caches and restart, all to no avail.

Note really sure what resources to include here... the following are snippets of what may be relevant.

From `build.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':playLicensing')
    compile 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.0'
    compile 'com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher:0.8.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.1-android'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
}
```

and from `proguard-rules.pro`:

```
-dontwarn com.google.**
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int w(...);
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
}
-printmapping mapping.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured out what the problem was.  With the [previous in-app billing implementation](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html), there was a [requirement](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-add-aidl) to place an `IInAppBillingService.aidl` file into an `aidl` subfolder in your project.  This is mine:

[image]

I had removed all the old billing stuff except for that file... but now that I've removed that too, all is fine with building my app with the new Play Billing Library.

Answer (score -1):

The same issue is happening to me but with the goolge services auth. The problem is that I don't even use that lib. No idea how to solve this...